# why I can't login to cPanel, shows error Maximum Users Exceeded?

Tags: authentication, server, cpanel

When I try to login to cPanel,

it shows an error **Maximum Users Exceeded**. please see the error message below. I didn't do any changes to server. this appears very suddenly. how can I fix this? I searched for google on this error but couldn't find anything helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That message says that the number of accounts on the server allows only limited users to access the account. Here are some ways to solve this:

1. You can remove unnecessary accounts.
2. Or you can upgrade the account to allow for more users to access it.

In my case the licence was expired and showing the same message Maximum user Exceeded, As soon as I renewed my account this issue was solved.